# How to use multiple JSON fields with the same name

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I want to use two different type adapters for each field, this is using GSON 2.7.

I am getting the error “class declares multiple JSON fields named type”

```java
public abstract class Vehicle 
{
    @SerializedName("type")
    @JsonAdapter(VehicleTypeAdapter.class)
    protected String type;
}
```

```java
public class Car extends Vehicle
{ 
    @SerializedName("type")
    @JsonAdapter(CarTypeAdapter.class)
    protected CarType carType;
}
```

How to avoid this error? I tried using `transient` but it did not work.

Comment: Problem appears that you want to override the behaviour of type in `Car`. You might be able to achieve this using annotations on accessor methods for the type field.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: How's about change your json? It's really bad practice as your json above.

Comment: Agree, but JSON cannot be changed.

Comment: @KenenisaBekele Are you mappings supposed to be serialized or deserialized?

Comment: Both, Serialised and Deserialised

Comment: Hey bro, have you found any solution? I'm also trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you can't have duplicate instances of a name used to serialize a field.

However, it doesn't look like you're trying to define two separate fields, but instead you're trying to create a more specific implementation of `type` in your `Car` class.

Unfortunately, by using `extends` you are *adding onto* the `Vehicle` abstract class rather than implementing a specific instance of `type`, so you can't change the definition of the inherited field.

Therefore, it looks like you've got a couple options:

- Drop `CarType` altogether, and just use `String type` as inherited from the superclass.
- If `CarType` is important to your implementation, you can change `String type` to `VehicleType vehicleType` and have `CarType` inherit from `VehicleType`, still removing the duplicate field from the `Car` subclass.

This means that you'll only have 1 `@JsonAdapter` so this option only works if creating a generic `TypeAdapter.class` is a possible solution.

- If you really must redefine the field, you'll have to turn `Vehicle` into an interface so that you can shadow/redefine within a more specific scope. Not sure if this is viable for your application.